# Why does DateTime.Now.ToBinary() returns different value than when created by constructor

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, deserialization

This is what I've tried:

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
long timeA = now.ToBinary();
long timeB = new DateTime(now.Year, now.Month, now.Day, now.Hour, now.Minute, now.Second, now.Millisecond).ToBinary();

Debug.WriteLine("{0} {1}", timeA, timeB);
```

This is the output:

```
-8588637543837682554 634734565017110000
```

The `timeA` and `timeB` should essentially be the same thing, but they are converted to a totally different (negative) binary.

Why does this happen? Why does directly calling `ToBinary()` on `DateTime.Now` produce different results?

**EDIT**: Since my issue was misunderstood (and thus downvoted) I have corrected my post to better represent the real question. The problem was in DateTime.Kind and that was the real issue, not the small difference in two consecutive DateTime.Now calls.

Comment: There's ever the slightest difference between the values.

Comment: :-O why would you expect these to be the same thing? Did you not realise half way through typing the second part, "hang on, something feels different here"

Comment: I believe every downvote should be explained, otherwise it's not contributing to SO but destroying it. I also believe that my question had some merit. If it hadn't, the answer would not have been given. Therefore I am grateful to people who tried to see what bothers me instead of picking on irrelevant things in my code. @musefan: yes, something feels different, it feels different for some ticks, not by the sign. So, please next time, try to provide an answer (relevant one) instead of non-constructive criticism. Nobody was helped by your comment.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but your question isn't very good. 1) You claim the result of `ToBinary` is "wrong", which IMO is an unfortunate choice of words, since it works as it should, just not as you expected. 2) The documentation clearly states that `ToBinary` encodes the `Kind`, which could have answered your question.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: about first, you are correct. If question title was being asked for after answers are given I'd definitely give it another line. I will change my question. Thanks for the advice. About the second, the docs didn't say that DateTime.Now has Local and new DateTime() overloads (that do not specify the kind) Unspecified. I assumed (incorrectly) that the two would be the same. Thank you for your comment. I'd say this IS the constructive comment that does contribute to SO.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are not the same `DateTime` values so this is expected.

To work on the same value of `DateTime` you need to call the `DateTime.Now` just once and then reuse it.

```
var now = DateTime.Now;
long timeA = now.ToBinary();
long timeB = new DateTime(now.Ticks, now.Kind).ToBinary();;

Console.WriteLine(timeA);
Console.WriteLine(timeB);
```

Comment: Calling `Now` twice is not the issue - the numbers would be a lot closer. It's the `Kind` bit that makes the first value negative.

Comment: I should have been more clear in that part, but I for one would not make any assumptions on how close the numbers should be since that's an implementation detail.

Comment: This still gives different results, so I don't think it's the intended answer.

Comment: @Davio, you are totally correct, the only constructor overload that will create an exact match will be `DateTime(long ticks, DateTimeKind kind)`. Answer updated, thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 11):

Your two values have a different `Kind`, and the kind gets also serialized by `ToBinary`.

`DateTime.Now` has `Kind == DateTimeKind.Local`, the DateTime you create with `new DateTime(...)` has `Kind == DateTimeKind.Unspecified`. You can use another overload for `new DateTime(...)` if you want a different kind.

Answer (score 3):

First you have to use [`DateTime.FromBinary()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.datetime.frombinary.aspx) to (re-)create the same `DateTime` object again.

But this may differ from the oroginal object too which is caused by local time differences. Please look at [this MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.datetime.tobinary.aspx) article which exaplains this in detail.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, firstly the two DateTimes have a different `Kind`.
`DateTime.Now` is of Kind Local, the second is of Kind Unspecified.

```
var now = DateTime.Now;
var timeA = now.ToBinary();
var dateB = new DateTime(now.Year, now.Month, now.Day, now.Hour, now.Minute, now.Second, now.Millisecond, now.Kind);
var timeB = dateB.ToBinary();
Console.WriteLine(timeA);
Console.WriteLine(timeB);
```

This produces different results:

```
-8588637530157241842
-8588637530157245808
```

Using ticks gives the correct results however, this is because ticks use 100 nanosecond intervals which is even more accurate thant the milliseconds.

The milliseconds are the smallest you can specify, but not the smallest internal variable.

```
var dateB = new DateTime(now.Ticks, now.Kind);
```

Comment: Try `long timeB = new DateTime(now.Ticks, DateTimeKind.Local).ToBinary();` The overload you used for DateTime seem not be granular as ticks are.

Comment: This gives the correct results. Indeed the overload with all the different parameters is somewhat off...

Comment: All is in the precision needed (IMO).

Answer (score 0):

Between the two calls of DateTime.Now, miliseconds pass, those make the two values different

Comment: Yes, but that's not the issue. The values would differ only in a few ticks (if at all). However, I have changed my question to better describe the problem.

Comment: @Kornelije Sorry, so the real question was, why was the first one negative right?